# Find the successor node in the BST after any key

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need implement method who searching next node after **any arbitrary** key. For example BST has keys `{0, 2, 4, 6, 8}`. For key `1` result must be `2` and for key `4` result must be `6`.

After some research by google and SO, I implement it this way(C#-like pseudocode):

```cs
class TreeNode
{
    int Key;
    TreeNode Left;
    TreeNode Right;
}

class Tree
{
    TreeNode Root;

    TreeNode FindNextNode(int key)
    {
        TreeNode node = Root;
        TreeNode succ = null;

        while (node != null) {

            if (key >= node.Key) {
                node = node.Right;
                continue;
            }

            succ = node;
            node = node.Left;
        }

        return succ;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be good and even works, but such a simple implementation makes me think that I have missed whatsoever.

Is my implementation correct?

**Upd:** Picture for discussion
[image]

Comment: Is this correct: `if (key >= null) {`? In Java this would not be possible at all. You are comparing an integer to a `null`. This does not make sense.

Comment: @gil.fernandes fixed

Comment: What happens, if the key you are trying to find is not in the tree? Are you planning to return the nearest node?

Comment: @gil.fernandes yes. At the beginning of the question there is an example. For the key is greater than all others return null

Comment: Another thing: if the `key == node.key` why not just return it straight away? Instead you move right in the tree. This might lead to an error. If you found the key just return immediately, do not continue traversal.

Comment: @gil.fernandes A good remark I did not consider this case. But it looks like the algorithm works as it should. Look at the picture in question. Suppose we need to find the following value from 14.
Even if you interrupt the cycle when 14 is found, then it will be necessary to shift to the right and then proceed to the left as far as it will go. In other words, the tracking path will be 14 -> 22 -> 18 -> 16. My implementation will essentially do the same

Comment: Sorry, you are correct about what you say. I was thinking about the ceiling function when I mentioned returning on equality.

Comment: Have you considered the case the user is searching beyond the last number in the tree; Let us say 1000 in your example.

Comment: @gil.fernandes Yes, I checked the left and right "borders"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at it for a while, the implementation looks correct in the latest version. There was this error mentioned in the comments:

```
`if (key >= null) {`
```

Also the left and right borders seem to be handled correctly. If the search key is beyond the maximum, `null` is returned. A search below the minimum should also return the first element in the list.

My only concern is that there is no `null` check for the input parameter. Perhaps some input parameter checking would make this implementation more robust.

I would also prefer not to use `continue` and use else instead.

Here is a version of this method in Kotlin enforcing non null search parameters and using `else` instead of `continue`:

```
fun next(key: Key): Key? {
    var node = root
    var succ: Node<Key, Value>? = null

    while (node != null) {
        if (key >= node.key) {
            node = node.right
        }
        else {
            succ = node
            node = node.left
        }
    }

    return succ?.key
}
```